# Create k size permutations without to define more functions

Tags: scheme, racket

is it possible to implement Scheme function (one function - its important) that gets a list and k, and retreive the permutations in size of k, for example: (1 2 3), k=2 will output { (1,1) , (1,2) , (1,3) , (2,1) , (2,2) , ..... } (9 options).?

Comment: Of course it is. What have you tried?

Comment: What do you mean by define more functions? You mean you only want to expose one global or are you restricted from creating local functions as well? Is it ok with anonymous functions? You most likely won't get answers that contain code unless your question show effort. Show us what you have tried so far! Use the edit button.

Answer (score -1):

Its possible to do anything without defining anything as long as you have lambda:

```scm
(define (fib n)
  ;; bad internal definition
  (define (helper n a b)
    (if (zero? n)
        a
        (helper (- n 1) b (+ a b))))
  (helper n 0 1))
```

Using Z combinator:

```
(define Z
  (lambda (f)
    ((lambda (g)
       (f (lambda args (apply (g g) args))))
     (lambda (g)
       (f (lambda args (apply (g g) args)))))))

(define (fib n)
  ((Z (lambda (helper)
        (lambda (n a b)
          (if (zero? n)
              a
              (helper (- n 1) b (+ a b))))))
   n 0 1))
```

Now we are never calling Z so we can substitute the value of Z for Z in the function and it will do the same:

```
(define (fib n)
  (((lambda (f)
      ((lambda (g)
         (f (lambda args (apply (g g) args))))
       (lambda (g)
         (f (lambda args (apply (g g) args))))))
    (lambda (helper)
      (lambda (n a b)
        (if (zero? n)
            a
            (helper (- n 1) b (+ a b))))))
   n 0 1))
```

There you go, Saved by [Alonzo Church](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alonzo_Church).

Answer (score -1):

It is not only possible, it is easy. Just use a `loop`:

```
(define permute
  (lambda (k lst)
    (let loop ((result (map list lst))
               (i 1))
      (if (= i k)
          result
          (loop
           ;; code to add each element of the original list
           ;; to each element of the result list
           (1+ i))))))
```